# Eclipselink loaded object and JMS Serialization

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, jms, eclipselink

We have a Glassfish 5 application server with severals war modules and some Java applications clients which are communicating between JMS and Rest webservices.

The server app load objects from databases using Eclipselink and, when needed, send them through JMS automatically. 
Now I'm facing a problem when deserializing the object on the client side because JMS throws a
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList` exception. The thing is that I do not have any IndirectList object in my entity but I assume that it is EclipseLink which instanciate my object Lists as IndirectList. 
The question is, why when recovering the object on the client side, it tries to instantiate IndirectList instead of List or ArrayList (I put the MyObject.class in the getBody() Method of JMS) ?
I can correct the error by adding eclipselink dependence on the client side but I'm not satisfied by this solution since I normally don't need it...

I hope I well explained my problem. 
Thank you.

Comment: IndirectList is used for lazy collections, so that EclipseLink can populate the collection when you try to access it. Don't use a lazy relationship if you are trying to serialize the data across - if it isn't triggered before it is sent, accessing it on the other side will give you an exception anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` is to add the missing class to your classpath. It's really as simple as that.

For what it's worth, I usually discourage people from using the JMS ObjectMessage for this exact kind of reason. Unless the object you put into the message is *extremely* simple you wind up adding classes to your client that may not really be necessary except to deserialize another object. Also, serialization and deserialization of Java objects is quite slow. I usually recommend that applications exchange data via simple byte arrays or even use something like JSON (although JSON can be slow there are faster alternatives).